# Find the dimensions of a piece of paper with smallest area (optimization)

Tags: calculus, optimization

Question: There is a piece of paper with the top and bottom margins being 1.5 inches and the left and right margins being 1 inches. There is $24$  $\textrm{in}^2$ of printed area.

So, in order to solve this question, I would need to find the min value of the Area.

**My Steps:**

$$
A = (h-3)(w-2)
$$

Then I can solve for $h$:

$$
h  =  \frac{24}{h-3} + 3
$$

then I can solve for $A$ in terms of $w$:

$$
A(w) = (w-2)\left(\frac{24}{w-2} + 3\right)
$$

I can take the derivative and find the crit point

$$
\begin{align}
A'(w) &= w\left(\frac{24}{w-2} + 3\right) + (w-2)\left(\frac{-24}{(w-2)^2}\right)\\
0 &= w\left(\frac{24}{w-2} + 3\right) + (w-2)\left(\frac{-24}{(w-2)^2}\right)\\
w &= \frac{10}{9}
\end{align}
$$

therefore, I can plug in $w$ into the Area function and find $h$

$$
\begin{align}
24 &= \left(\frac{10}{9} - 2\right)(h-3)\\
h &= 30
\end{align}
$$

However, when you plug in $30$ and $\frac{10}{9}$ into the original Area equation, you get $-24$ instead of $24$. I am confused as to why this is happening because I can not think of any other way to get the proper answer.

Comment: Your equation for $h$ is wrong.  It should be $h=\frac {24}{w-2}+3$ but you correct that later.  You use $A$ both for the printed area and the area of the whole sheet.  For the whole sheet you have $A=hw$ and it is this you should substitute your equation for $h$ then take the derivative with respect to $w$.  It helps to write down what your variables represent, especially when you show your work to others (or to your future self).

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to find the smallest paper with such margins and printed area?
That is,
$$
\arg\min S=h*w \quad s.t. \quad (h-3)(w-2)=24 \quad 0<h,w
$$
This is easy to find,
$$
S = \frac{24w}{w-2} + 3w\\
S^{'} = -\frac{48}{(w-2)^2} + 3
$$
S get minimun 54 at $w=6, h = 9$